# Capistrano: Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I am trying to use Capistrano for deploying a rails App. If i try to run "cap production deploy", i get the error "Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile'"

If i run "rake assets:precompile" on the server, i get the same error.

Gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
    gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
    # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
    gem 'sqlite3'
    # Use SCSS for stylesheets
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
    # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    # Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

    # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:     https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
    gem 'turbolinks'
    # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
    # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

    # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
    gem 'spring',        group: :development

    # Use Capistrano for deployment
    gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1'
    gem 'capistrano-bundler'#, '~> 1.1.2'
    gem 'capistrano-rails'#, '~> 1.1.1'

    gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.0'
```

Capfile:

```
    # Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
    require 'capistrano/setup'

    # Includes default deployment tasks
    require 'capistrano/deploy'

    require 'capistrano/rbenv'

    require 'capistrano/bundler'

    require 'capistrano/rails'

    require 'capistrano/rails/assets'

    set :rbenv_type, :user # or :system, depends on your rbenv setup

    Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Comment: You say, you ran `cap production install`, but that initialize capistrano, did you ran `cap production deploy`?

Comment: Sorry, i ran `cap production deploy`, not `cap production install`. Thanks!